# Single digit followed by two alphabets regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regular expression. I need a regular expression to validate single digit within range of [1-5] followed by alphabet [A-C] and followed by optional alphabet [X-Z]

- 1A  (Valid)
- 2BZ (Valid)
- 7B  (Invalid)

Comment: And what have you attempted?

Comment: Yes I tried [1-5][a-cA-C][x-zX-Z]? but it also validates 1aA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you tried is right, except you're missing the start and end characters, so it's succeeding on a partial match.

You need:

```
^[1-5][a-cA-C][x-zX-Z]?$
```

Comment: Thanks it worked by adding start and end characters

Answer (score 0):

Use online testers to validate it:

```
[1-5]+[A-C]+[X-Z]*
```

[regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)

[gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/)